# ModuleNotFoundError - Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I have read the documentation on what to do if you want the directories to be treated as packages: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html. i.e. one needs `__init__.py` files in such directories. I followed the instructions and created a folder structure that contains these files:

[image]

Screenshot you are looking at has the structure on the left that reflects that of the documentation. On the right is the code (`routes.py`; you can see it as the last file in the folder structure on the left) that gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "routes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app.static.python.sections_elements import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

all of the `__init__.py` files are empty, except for the `__init__.py` in python folder. Which contains two lines of code:

```
__all__ = ['sections_elements.py']
```

i.e. `__all__` declaration and an empty line.

Can you let me know what am I missing here? Why am I getting this error? ( I am running `python routes.py`)

Comment: First thing first don't name a folder python in your project, unnecessary catastrophy. Also does app folder have `__init__.py`?

Comment: I'll rename it now. Thanks. Yes, it is below the templates folder on that screenshot. It is also empty

Comment: Looking at that file structure, I'm unsure what you're trying to import. Does `app` have a `app` class inside it?

Comment: Are you sure you need to specify `app` in your import? I think `static.python.sections_element` should be enough.

Comment: @Laszlowaty if I do static.python.sections_element I get unresolved reference

Comment: @Batman that python modules just includes a couple of "constants" declarations that I moved to a different module (sections_elements) to avoid the cluttering of the routes module.

Comment: Something I noticed just now: if I execute the code in the IDE without the app part, like @Laszlowaty said, it works from the shell. If I leave the app beginning in, then it works from the IDE but not the shell....

Comment: If I see it correct, routes.py is inside "app" folder. So as Laszlowaty said, you cannot import it as the top package, and instead should start one level below.

Comment: when I do that I get a syntax error for some reason in the IDE... But it does work then from the shell